# Acronyms aren't being listed, so can I preprocess only the \input s?

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, input

So, my true problem is that overleaf doesn't generate a glossary. I suspect that the problem is that I have sub-files with `\input{}`.

Therefore my question is: is there a way to let latex create a single `.tex` file with all `\input` commands executed. I would then be able to input this single one into overleaf and compile it.

<s>Allright. I have a MVCE. Overleaf project found here: [https://www.overleaf.com/9283383875ffmqsbpqjcnf][1]</s>

You can see that no glossary is being generated. This though everything is just about right.

The files are:

> main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\include{config}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\input{chapters/0_abstract}

\printglossaries


\end{document}
```

> config.tex

```
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\input{acronym}
```

> acronym.tex

```
\newacronym{TVLA}{TVLA}{Test Vector Leakage Assessment}
\newacronym{CPA}{CPA}{Correlation Power Analysis}
\newacronym{DPA}{DPA}{Differential Power Analysis}
\newacronym{SCA}{SCA}{Side Channel Analysis}
```

> chapters/0_abstract.tex

```
\chapter{Abstract}
Here goes your abstract. Be concise, introduce context, problem, known approaches, your solution, your findings.

\acrshort{CPA}
\cite{2004_CPA_with_power_model}
```

Comment: Without any provided code how should we know what you are doing?

Comment: the answer to the actual question is "no" but if you said what you did, what error you got and what you wanted to happen, someone could give some help.

Comment: use of `\input` has essentially no effect on any glossary constructs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the straightforward answer. As for the rest, I'll try to create a MVCE and update my original question with it. As for the quick problem desc: no errors, just doesn't add the glossary at the end of the document. Package is included and debugging with the default overleaf example doc didn't give any help.

Comment: the command to include the glossary will either find a generated glossary and include it or give a warning that it is not there, so you must have _some_ information in the log relevant to your problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the MVCE. I can't find anything that stands out in the logs. I've also added a MVCE overleaf project so you can see the logs easily.

Comment: @daleif please see the MVCE

Comment: Not very M(inmal) :-)  (you could surely have inlined the preamble and only had one chapter. I'll look though. Probably not releated but `\include{config}` is wrong never use `\include` in the preamble.

Comment: Please make sure your example is **minimal**. As David already mentioned, there is no difference between code inputted and code online, so the external chapters can be replaced.

Comment: @TarickWelling, I suggest working backwards with a minimal new document, to localize the problem. I.e. start with one "big" file, which DOES generate the glossary. Next, move parts, e.g. sections to a separate file and ` \input ´ it. See, if and where the line breaks, so to say. // Chances are, you deal with a different problem, like settings, options etc.

Comment: you had not used `\glossarystyle{...}`  [tested at your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w43va.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought it was something to do with the `config.tex` but it seems my problem was the `\include` vs a `\input`. With `\input` it works. So if you want to add this as an answer then I'll accept.

Comment: it was adding \glossarystyle not changing \include that made the difference I think?

Comment: I just checked in my bigger project and only include->input works. Adding glossarystyle as in the shared project does not do anything in the bigger project

Comment: And for all who helped. Thank you very much. And my excuses for the big MVCE, I indeed should've cut that one down more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\include` should never be used in the preamble (the file will get input, but `aux` file usage will break)  use `\input`  (or better rename the file to `.sty` and use `\usepackage`)

Also Overleaf requires `\glossarystyle{list}` (or some other defined style) to trigger the automatic generation.  With those changes you get

[image]